# Replacing strings with special characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I'm looking to replace strings inside DataFrame columns, these strings contain special characters.

I tried the following, but nothing changed in the DataFrame:

```
data = {'col1': ["series ${z_mask0}", "series ${z_mask1}", "series ${z_mask2}"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

old_values = ["${z_mask0}", "${z_mask1}", "${z_mask2}"]

new_values = ["${z_00}", "${z_01}", "${z_02}"]

df = df.replace(old_values_sign, new_values_sign, regex=True)
print(df)
```

The intended output is:
['series ${z_00}', 'series ${z_01}', 'series ${z_02']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the $ character using `\` in the `old_values` list:

```
old_values = ["\${z_mask0}", "\${z_mask1}", "\${z_mask2}"]
```

The above should be enough. Here is all the code:

```
old_values = ["\${z_mask0}", "\${z_mask1}", "\${z_mask2}"]
new_values = ["${z_00}", "${z_01}", "${z_02}"]
df = df.replace(old_values, new_values, regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      col1
0   series ${z_00}
1   series ${z_01}
2   series ${z_02}
```

Comment: Works great if the list is short as the one I posted, but I have a second case where the old_values is too long for me to add "\" manually. I'm editing my question based on your answer

Comment: Well, I think that if your editions are a lot, you should open a new question. :)

Comment: Okay I'll revert my question to how it was and open a new question :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does escaping work where raw strings don't? I was under the impression that they were (more or less) equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using raw strings for the `old_values`? There are some RegEx characters in there that may be interfering with your result ("{", "}", and "$"). Try this instead:

```
old_values = [r"${z_mask0}", r"${z_mask1}", r"${z_mask2}"]
```

Note the `r` before each string

Comment: I did try it, but nothing changed as well.